# Show div when image is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used the `onClick` function to change an image on click. 
I want a `div` below the image to only display when the image has been clicked. How do I show this div only when the image has been clicked?

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png"
onclick="this.src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png'"> 

<div class="showme"> my text</div>
```

Comment: Set the style to `display:none;` using `css` and then target that div in javascript to change the `css` when you change the src of that image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With jquery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        $('.showme').show();
    })
})
```

```css
.showme {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png"> 
<div class="showme"> my text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hide your div first,then on click change the property of the div to block.

**here is the snippet code :**

```js
    function show()
    {
     $('.showme').css('display','block');
    }
```

```css
    .showme{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://localhost:8888/ek/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/unselect1-1.jpg" onclick="show()">

<div class="showme"> my text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS style and jQuery:

```js
$('#active').click(function() {
$('.showme').css('display', 'block');
  }
)
//or img attr replace
$('#activeimg').click(function() {
$('#activeimg').attr('src', 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconsmind/outline/128/Smile-icon.png');
  }
)
```

```css
.showme {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://localhost:8888/ek/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/unselect1-1.jpg" alt="click" id="active">
<hr />
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/42/42877.png" title="click" id="activeimg">

<div class="showme">my text</div>
```